# Overcoming cross-browser issues designing UI elements

Tags: css, cross-browser

I'm currently changing the look of `select` elements on my page and I noticed that almost every browser displays all the effects differently. That is not so bad alone but I also noticed that some browsers do not support some effects at all, for example Chrome does not support background image, rounded corners and probably something else I've not yet noticed.

I have seen some pretty impressive drop down menus on some websites where everything has been custom made, starting from the glows to the appearance of the arrow button and so on.

How is it done? Is it done with some Javascript/jQuery plugin?
Can anyone point me to some good resources?

Comment: try http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/ ....

Comment: All you'd really require JavaScript for is open/close states based on onmouseup events, the rest is ordinary HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you go down the path of a jquery plugin. Doing a search for "jquery select box" returns a number of useful results, eg:

http://www.designdim.com/2011/07/10-important-jquery-selectboxdropdown-plugins/

I have tried out a number of these before, and some are more flexible than others.

One that I really like that is not in that list is [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/), although it doesn't fully support IE7 and 8.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Few hours after I asked the question here I found one of the plugins listed on the page you linked. Your link is better so I choose yours as the best answer.